# <class> not a constructor error at runtime

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I am using following classes:
I got a root class :

```
class BasePage {
    constructor() {
        this.root = "rootbase";
    }
}
module.exports = BasePage;
```

Extended by 2 subclasses:

```
const Page2 = require('./page2')
const BasePage = require("./basePage")

class Page1 extends BasePage {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.root = "root1";
    }
    open2() {
        global.plop = new Page2()
    }
}

module.exports = Page1;
```

```
const Page1 = require('./page1')
const BasePage = require("./basePage")

class Page2 extends BasePage {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.root = "root2";
    }
    open1() {
        global.plop = new Page1()
    }
}

module.exports = Page2;
```

When I am running

```
    global.plop = new BasePage();
    global.plop = new Page1();
    plop.open2();
    plop.open1();
```

I get

```
ncaught TypeError TypeError: Page1 is not a constructor
    at open1 (c:\Users\Amira\Projects\nodetemp\page2.js:10:17)
    at main (c:\Users\Amira\Projects\nodetemp\index.js:11:10)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\Amira\Projects\nodetemp\index.js:15:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at executeUserEntryPoint (internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at <anonymous> (internal/main/run_main_module:23:47)
```

What I am missing ? Is there any workaround ?

no workaround found ...
also tried with `Reflect.construct()` instead of new unsuccessfully

Comment: I suspect that the `Page1` class in `global.prop = new Page1()` might be `undefined` because of the circular imports; could you try adding `console.log(Page1)` before that line and see what it outputs?

Comment: you have circular references.

Comment: console.log result `{}`

Comment: any pattern to avoid it ?